# How can the TCP read the IP address in demultiplexing?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming, ip

Most of the computer network books explaining the TCP/IP stack by mentioning that: when a layer received its PDU (whether it is a frame or a segment...) do the following:

- Examine the fields, do some stuff and decide whether or not to pass the message to the layer above it.
- If the layer decided to pass the message the layer above it, the above layer will again do the same previous step after ( REMOVING the the previous layer header ).

If that is true, the question arises: how TCP knows the source IP address (that in network layer header) which will be used to move segments to their appropriate sockets.

Thank in advance!

Comment: In the case of a TCP socket it's already associated with the socket; in the case of UDP it is part of the data to be delivered every to the applications so it is provided to the UDP layer. But the layering isn't as squeaky-clean as some texts imply, or state. There's plenty of peeking under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they say in the (introductory) textbooks about the packet traversal in the network stack is just pedagogical. If we look at how it is implemented, it is much more complicated. Let us consider Linux.

- The article, [The journey of a packet through the Linux 2.4 network stack](http://ftp.gnumonks.org/pub/doc/packet-journey-2.4.html) by Harald Welte summarizes the packet traversal at different stages.

I am quoting the relevant part of the article to answer your question.

1. The IP packet handler is registered via net/core/dev.c:dev_add_pack() called from net/ipv4/ip_output.c:ip_init().
2. The IPv4 packet handling function is net/ipv4/ip_input.c:ip_rcv(). After some initial checks (if the packet is for this host, ...) the ip checksum is calculated. Additional checks are done on the length and IP protocol version 4. Every packet failing one of the sanity checks is dropped at this point.
3. After successful traversal, net/ipv4/ipv_input.c:ip_rcv_finish() is called. Inside ip_rcv_finish(), the packet's destination is determined by calling the routing function net/ipv4/route.c:ip_route_input(). Furthermore, if our IP packet has IP options, they are processed now. Depending on the routing decision made by net/ipv4/route.c:ip_route_input_slow(), the journey of our packet continues in one of the following functions:

   - net/ipv4/ip_input.c:ip_local_deliver() : The packet's destination is local, we have to process the layer 4 protocol and pass it to an userspace process.
   - net/ipv4/ip_forward.c:ip_forward() : The packet's destination is not local, we have to forward it to another network
   - net/ipv4/route.c:ip_error() : An error occurred, we are unable to find an appropriate routing table entry for this packet.
   - net/ipv4/ipmr.c:ip_mr_input() : It is a Multicast packet and we have to do some multicast routing.

**NOTE:** Some traversal stages related to the Netfilter hooks are skipped. Please refer to the original article for all the stages.

`net/ipv4/in_input.c:ip_local_deliver()` is the function we are interested in. As described, it processes the layer-4 protocol and passes it to userspace. How it is implemented can be seen from the Linux kernel code, to cut short, there is no harm in assuming that `ip_local_deliver()` is aware of layer-3 details.

Comment: @IbrahimAlnefisi Since you are new to the community, please give a refresh to this link [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)